# PHP 5.3 and assigning the return value of new by reference

Tags: php

Assigning the return value of new by reference has been [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) in PHP 5.3. As such,

```
$obj =& new Foo();
```

now throws an `E_DEPRECATED` error.

When upgrading a large application with a lot of legacy code to 5.3, this leads to a lot of unwanted notices.

As a potential fix to this problem, I am considering using a regular expression to find and replace all instances of `=& new` with `= new`. For example, the following will find all PHP files, and wipe out all instances of `=& new`:

```
find ./ -name '*.php' | xargs perl -p -i -e 's/=(\s*)&(\s*)?new\b/= new/g'
```

Looking for answers to the following questions:

1. Will it work just fine? What potential issues might I run into?
2. If not, examples of code where replacing `=& new` with `= new` will change the behavior in PHP 5.3.
3. Any examples of popular libraries with this would be known to cause a problem.
4. What other ideas do you recommend to deal with fixing massive amounts of  `=& new`?

I suspect this will work just fine, but looking for edge cases where I might run into trouble. Yes, I know I could just change the error reporting settings. But I don't want to hide the notices, I want to fix them.

Comment: E_DEPRECATED belongs to the class of notices, not errors. I'm not sure you need to hurry with fixing it (magic_quotes were declared deprecated in php 4.2 or so). As for the regex: you should add a `\b` after the `new`, but otherwise it's a workable rewrite approach. But you can only test if it impairs the expected processing logic (unlikely though).

Comment: @mario E_DEPRECATED is just an error *level*. It'd be appropriate to refer to it either way. Good point with \b though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your feeling is right. It will generally work fine, but there are edge cases where it doesn't.

Using `=&` has these differences with `=`:

- `=&` will try to make the right side yield a reference; `=` won't -- even if the right side is able to yield a reference, like a function which returns by reference.
- `=&` will break the old reference set and put the left and the right side both in a new one, while `=` will change the value of all the elements in the same reference set as the left side to the value of the right side.

The first difference and half of the second is irrelevant in this case. After the assignment, there will be only one variable with the value of the new object*, and single-element reference sets make no sense. However, the fact that `=&` breaks the previous reference set is significant:

```
<?php

$g = 4;
$v =& $g;
$v = new stdclass();
var_dump($g); // object(stdClass)#1 (0) { }

$g = 4;
$v =& $g;
$v =& new stdclass();
var_dump($g); // int(4)
```

* Unless maybe the constructor leaks a reference, but even if it leaks, `$this` inside the constructor may be a different variable, even if it points to the same object. So I doubt one could observe behavior difference due to this.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the breakage of old references.  But typo, it should be `=&`, not `&=`.

Comment: Wow, cool stuff. Never would have thought that it makes a difference. +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should be able to just replace `=& new` with `= new`.  Objects are passed by reference by default in PHP 5.3, so no behavior will change.

+1 for fixing notices instead of hiding them.

Comment: +1 (Obligatory "references passed by value, not objects passed by reference" pedantry goes here.)

Comment: -1 Wrong and irrelevant. They are not interchangeable and no-one's passing anything (except constructor arguments) by reference or by value...

Comment: @Artefacto: Aren't they interchangeable though?  When creating a new object, there should be no difference between passing it to a variable by reference or by value anyway.  And what exactly is irrelevant?

Comment: @Jonah The first sentence is wrong (see my answer for an example where they lead to different results) and the second sentence is irrelevant because nothing is being passed -- it is an assignment, not a function call.

Comment: I see.  Obviously I hadn't considered that case.  But I still don't quite understand what you're saying about the second sentence...

Comment: @Jonah You can only talk about "passing by reference" if there is a function call involved and we are passing it something. In this case, there is a function call (the call to the constructor), but we're not passing it anything (`new Foo()`) and even if we were, the way the arguments should be passed would not be affected by `&=` vs `=`. You could only -- arguably -- talk about return by reference.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any problems. In the worst case this will slow down your application on PHP 4 slightly, but it definitely won't change functionality.

The only problem you could theoretically run into, is that somebody wrote `=& new` in a string. I know, this is highly improbable, but if you want to replace really only all occurences of `'=' T_WHITESPACE? '&' T_WHITESPACE? T_NEW` you should do so using the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/tokenizer).

Comment: Sure, but maybe that could be a good thing. If someone had "example usage" of some code in a comment, the regex would fix the example usage. But I suppose it would be bad if it was an example of what not to do :-)

Comment: They are not the same thing. Good point with `=& new` appearing in a string though.