# Is PHP 5.3 backwards-compatible with PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, backwards-compatibility

I'm starting to learn PHP. I would like to use PHP 5.3 because it's the newest version so far. I'm working on a project in which I'll use PHP 5.2 scripts that someone gave me.

Are they going to run just fine even though I'm using PHP 5.3?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php should have all yhou need to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP.net features a [guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) for upgrading from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3. This includes a section on [backwards compatibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php).

From my experience, the transition from 5.2 to 5.3 went pretty smoothly smoothly. The only problems I had with my app was to ensure my DateTime setting were property configured in my php.ini, and filter out some overly-agressive deprecation warnings that started showing up.

Comment: +1. Really smooth transition for me as well. One issue I ran into is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673472/php-5-3-and-assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference

Answer (score 5):

No, 5.3 is not backward compatible, and by all means it shouldn't be seen as a minor version upgrade. 
There is a page dedicated to incompatible changes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php
Also consider functions you have designed but have been accepted into 5.3. Since php doesn't support overloading or overwriting of functions, this will give an error.

Comment: "consider functions you have designed but have been accepted into 5.3" wow, thats a rare/random thing to point out :D but why -1?

Comment: As for why I pointed it out: I've run across it on more than one occasion trying to run old applications with 5.3.  We had functions defined that now where php-lib functions (I think 'date_add' was among them), and it really breaks. And a global find-and-replace certainly takes more effort than you'd expect from a minor version update. As for why -1, I am curious as well.

Comment: Then why do they even increment the minor version if it's going to introduce backwards-incompatible changes? That sounds really awkward.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, minor version releases aren't going to cause you problems. You should be okay.

Obviously, if you do have any problems, you'll want to make sure you have `error_reporting` set to see all errors. [PHP: error_reporting](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Also, check the manual for changes in 5.3 from 5.2: [Migrating from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are some minor issues. Call time pass by reference are deprecated. There are new reserved words (ie. goto).

Answer (score 1):

php has no backward compatibility in all version. It often removed some functions when it changed version. The problem occurs when you have to upgrade server and need to change php version but some php scripts no longer work with new php version. You also have to correct php script which is a bigger job. But if the script belong to other users rather than yours, you can't upgrade those scripts. This is a real headache situation that I'm fed up with php and switch to perl instead for backward compatibility reason.