# PHP 5.3 code on 5.2 server?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.2

Right now my webhost only has a sever with the max php number of 5.2. I didn't realize this and coded entirely on Xamp with a 5.3.1 server. Is there any sort of php script or something that will allow me to run 5.3 code on a 5.2 server. One of the particular lines im having trouble with is this:

```
$files = array_diff( scandir( __DIR__ . '/data' ), array('.','..') );
require __DIR__ . '/views/view_index.php';
```

At about that line the php just doesn't read, and has issues. The view_index.php works on its own, but the line above doesn't seem to be working, since I need to pass that variable to read in some file names into a dropdown selector. Although, I have more problems, most of which will take a long time to solve. Is there any sort of script made to ease this process. I have been looking around and couldn't find any.

Comment: There is another post on this, that might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693575/is-php-5-3-backwards-compatible-with-php-5-2

Comment: You should consider changing the hosts: Even PHP5.4 is out ...

Comment: I know I tried, the problem is I am not exactly in charge of changing the webhost, and I asked the guy who is and he paid for two years... sigh

Comment: Change your xamp environment to 5.2 and fix your app to run in 5.2. Then you can migrate use it on your 5.2 host. Depending on the complexity of your app it shouldn't be too hard to convert it to 5.2 compat.

Answer (score 1):

As for the particular __DIR__ problem you wrote, you can do a search & replace and change it to this everywhere:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

this should result in the same as __DIR__.

Comment: Or just `define('__DIR__', dirname(__FILE__))` so that you don't have to change a ton of code...

Comment: @AlexHowansky NO, bad, that would define `__DIR__` as the same directory  no matter where you used it. There is a reason they are called 'magic' constants: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: I am a little new to this function, but when i try to edit it like the documentation says, it only shows me the files in the root directory, but I need to get the files in the directory one down from it called data

Comment: @user: Yes, this is a result of the effect noted in Aknosis' comment -- `__DIR__` changes depending on what file you're in, and my define wouldn't. So... nevermind. :)