# Assigning return value of new by reference is deprecated in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, migration, deprecated

My site has a deprecated error at this line:

```
$obj =& new $class($table,$primkeyArr,$this);
```

it is because of `&`. It gives this error:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in ....
```

It is a issue in php 5.3.

If I remove the `&` from this line, the error does away. But I don't know if it causes any problem if I put my site on a server with lower PHP version (5.2) or not.

Will removing the `&` work ok both in PHP 5.2 and in PHP 5.3?

Comment: "Will removing the & work ok both in PHP 5.2 and in PHP 5.3?" Yes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 5.3 and assigning the return value of new by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673472/php-5-3-and-assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP 5, objects are handled in a reference-like manner by default. So removing the `&` probably won't change anything.

But as assigning by reference breaks old references, [there might still be a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673472/php-5-3-and-assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference/4673828#4673828).

Answer (score 1):

It's not deprecated to return a reference but to not reflect that in your functions oder methods signature. There has to be an & before the name as well as when assigning the returned value.

```
public function &getValue() 
{
  return $this->value;
}

...

$myValue = &$obj->getValue();
```

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) will tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

It's a mere warning.  You don't really need it, but the short answer is that it will only throw warnings.  Depending on the level of error_handling in your php config will depend on if you see it on other 5.3 systems.